# Row-order and Figsize is not working in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, relplot

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
sns.relplot(kind='line',data=merge_wrp,x='month_name',y='Amount_tran',hue='Product',
             errorbar=None,row_order=['April','May','June','July', 'August','September',
                                      'October','November','December','January', 'February','March'])
plt.xticks(rotation=50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your data to the question and edit your post into something that looks like a question. Use code blocks for the code section. Tell a story about what you have tried so far

Comment: [`sns.replot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). Such functions use `height=...` and `aspect=...` to set the size of individual subplots (the width is height times aspect ratio). You should remove the call to `plt.figure()` as that creates an independent empty plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_order` and `col_order` don't refer to the `x-or-y axis` of one plot. It make sense if you use `col` and `row` parameters to draw more than one chart.
In your case, you have to sort your dataframe first. It can be done with [`pd.CategoricalDType`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html):

```
months = ['April','May','June','July', 'August','September', 
          'October','November','December','January', 'February','March']
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(months, ordered=True)

sns.relplot(data=merge_wrp.astype({'month_name': cat}),
            x='month_name', y='Amount_tran', hue='Product',
            kind='line', errorbar=None)

plt.xticks(rotation=50)
plt.show()
```